# Invalid conversion? Assigning a const pointer to a pointer

Tags: c++

```
blog blog::operator+(const blog * b)
{
    next = b; //blog * next; it's a next pointer in a doubly linked list.
    return * this;
}
```

I was just wondering if there was any way I could assign b to next pointer of the current node. Is there a different way that I could do it? Right now I'm getting

```
invalid conversion from ‘const blog*’ to ‘blog*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Looking back on my notes, it seems to suggest that I should use constants while doing operator overloading, but right now it isn't really compiling. How would I be able to cast the const blog * b into next pointer? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to? You can't modify constants without invoking undefined behaviour. Casting and forgetting is not a solution.

Comment: You're not supposed to, unless by summoning Satan and his `const_cast`. If this pointer has been marked as `const` in that context, it means it should not allow any way of modifying it.

Comment: Why are you using `operator+` to _assign_ a value to your object?

Comment: Perhaps try `blog * const b`?

Comment: Ok, so should I just do "blog * b" for all the operators that do changes, and use const for the operators that I plan on using for display etc? and @CaptainObvlious, I'm using it to add a node to a linked list, so I figured I would use that + for adding to a linked list

Comment: @CaptainObvlious That should be pretty obvlious, considering the name of the object that's being assigned to.

Comment: @ArnoSluismans If it was obvious I wouldn't have asked. Using `operator+` to assign a value is inconsistent with how that operator is _supposed_ to work. There's nothing to prevent you from doing it though but using `operator=` would be much more clearer and less confusing.

Comment: I was going to use + for add, - to remove, += to edit. Just because it's easier for me to look at and read. But @micaelb958, I used "blog * const b" it compiles now, but how does that work? I've never used a const after the type-specifier before

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your question and comments I understand you are confused about the meaning of `const blog *`.

You have to read the pointer types *backwards*.

- `blog *` is a pointer to blog - you may change the pointer value, you may change the pointed-to object with the pointer.
- `blog const *` (and `const blog *`) is a pointer to const blog - you may change the pointer value, but you can't change the object with this pointer.
- `blog * const` a const pointer to blog - you can't change the pointer value, but you still can change the pointed-to object with this pointer.

The confusion often arrises because you have **two** types that come to play here. The type of pointer and the pointed-to type. Both can be const.

With the interface of your `operator+` you guarantee the object pointed to by the parameter will not get changed by that pointer (pointer to const blog). But then you assign it to a pointer to blog, which then could be used to alter the object and break the interface contract. I suggest you rethink the interface or change the implementation of your operator - you might want to copy the contents of the pointed-to object into the internal list, instead of just manipulating with pointers.

Comment: You might also add that `const blog *` and `blog const *` are the same (especially since the latter is closer to "read the type backwards")

Comment: Perfect! I got confused because I knew const blog * and blog const * were the same thing, but when I saw blog * const that just really confused me! It's cleared up, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to cast const pointer to non-const pointer you can use `const_cast` as Gaurav suggested.

However, I would use something like that only as a last resort when I really cornered by someone else's lib/api I just have to use.

If this is happened in your own code this ususally mean that you are not designed your api/interface carefully and/or misuse/misunderstand "const correctness"

I strongly enourage you to read about [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html).

**UPDATE:** const corectness is not a just another fancy thing we have in C++. It may add some pain sometimes, but it also provides some room for assumptions to clients of your code as well as to compiler/optimizer. Doing `const_cast` literally "breaks the rules" and may easily lead to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`next = const_cast<blog *>(b)`**

const_cast will remove or cast away the constantness of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to overload operator+ ,different than its usual meaning and usage for your class, so you don't really need to declare your parameter as const. With that way you can tackle your problem

Answer (score 0):

your notes are probably referring to the usual case of binary operator overloading, where the two operands don't change (they are just used to create a result)

such as if you were overloading + or - to do arithmetic operations.

your parameter is a pointer to an object that isn't allowed to change, now as you have a linked list where the node data is stored in the class, this is not what you want as simply changing the list changes the objects.

using a cast to correct your error simply destroys the purpose of making you parameter const, you are better off just not making it const, which is probably fine for what you are doing.

operator overloads are just functions, there is no hard reason they should be more const than any other functions, that I can see.